# Android-приложение. Автозапуск.Запрет на закрытие

Tags: android, защита

Всем доброго времени суток!

Не подскажете, можно ли сделать так(программно), что бы:

1.Приложение запускалось автоматически, т.е. при запуске смартфона.

2.Было запущено в фоновом режиме(по максимуму никак не отображалось).

3.Нельзя было закрыть(или при закрытие оно вновь возовновлялось).

По-идеи из под root'а можно разрешить что угодно.

Comment: 1) можно
2) можно, но не нужно
3) а вот за такое нужно бить.

Comment: Я,конечно, понимаю, что краткость- сестра таланта, то не в такой же степени!)) 
По ip меня вычислишь?) ахахах

Comment: вам с root это делать надо или без?

Comment: Установить можно и из под root

Comment: именно в такой степени. А вычислять - оно мне нужно?

Comment: @KoVadim, приведу пример простого, но полезного приложения для которого оптимальны все три пункта- это локер приложений, чтобы при запуске приложения поверх выводился ввод пароля. Ввел не правильно- приложение закрывается.  
у меня стоит такой локер, но его защита легко снимается так: приложения- название приложения локера- остановить. Все. До перезагрузки никакой защиты.

Comment: Такая защита должна быть либо внутри приложения либо частью прошивки.

Answer (score 2):

[@danpetruk](/users/8694/danpetruk), спасибо. Вопрос про локер к теме правда не относится, да и сделать все можно не вникая глубоко во внутренности системы.
1. Просто автостарт системы вешая рецайвер `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`
2. Если нет активити, то будет запущено в фоне
3. Устанавливается два приложения, каждое из которых следит, чтобы другое было запущено, если одно приложение завершается второе его запускает.

Comment: Ну почти что так, только надо вешать как `Service` - тогда все будет путем.

Comment: @ReinRaus: а если заморозить все потоки в одном приложении, убить второе, потом убить первое? Или убить оба в двух потоках одновременно? :) На своём устройстве умный юзер всегда переиграет.

Comment: [Недавно было](http://hashcode.ru/questions/175868/service-android-фоновый-сервис). Сервис сам себя перезапускает периодически и запускается естественно на BOOT_COMPLETED. У меня такая система работает в gps-трекере, пользователи довольны.

Answer (score -1):

Найдите точку старта системы. Она написана либо на C, либо на C++. Там до запуска dalvik на c / c++ пропишите: 1. весь экран сделать белым 2. выполнять следующий код (запуск dalvik, launcher) только если будет введён пароль. Программку ввода пароля писать придётся самому. На том-же C/C++.

Comment: Слишком сложный способ - проще надо проще ребята!

Comment: Все таки минусану... извини, конечно, @danpetruk - но ради этого лезть в прошивку это примерно как удалять гланды через задний проход